# Exponential object in a category of graphs

Tags: category-theory

I define a digraph as a set $V$ (vertexes) and a relation $E$ (edges) on $V$.

Morphisms of digraph are functions which preserve $E$.

So we have a category.

Does this category have an exponential object? (and so is cartesian closed, I've already prove it has small products.)

Comment: This question was also answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/512832/43208 . The category of digraphs is not merely cartesian closed -- it is locally cartesian closed. Indeed, it is a Grothendieck quasitopos.

Answer (score 5):

This question is answered  positively with references to many older works on this area in the paper R. Brown, I. Morris, J. Shrimpton and C.D. Wensley, `Graphs of
Morphisms of Graphs',  *Electronic Journal of Combinatorics+*, A1 of
Volume 15(1), 2008. 1-28, available also [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/graphmorphisms-v15i1a1.pdf). Actually, in addition to the directed graphs you define there are also the *reflexive directed graphs*, which have functions $s,t: E \to V$ and a function $\epsilon: V \to E$ such that $s\epsilon=t\epsilon=1_V$. You should particularly notice the paper [15] by Lawvere referenced there. Actually, the categories of directed graphs of either type form a *topos*, which gives these categories many similarities to the category of sets, but also differences, e.g. their logic is not Boolean. One property of a topos is to have a *subobject classifier*, and this idea is well worth exploring: for the category of sets the subobject classifier is the set $\{0,1\}$ with the inclusion $\tau: \{1\} \to \{0,1\}$, often called "true".  You can try to work out for yourself what is the subobject classifier for your kind of directed graphs!

Actually it is standard that if $C$ is any small category, and $Sets$ is the category of sets and functions, then the functor category $(Sets)^C$ also has the structure of topos. So there are many potential applications of these ideas.

Comment: What your link calls directed graphs might more precisely be called directed _multi_graphs; they are not the same as what the question defined directed graphs to be because they can have more than one edge between the same pair of vertices.

Comment: Good point: a point I should have made is that usually in discussing morphisms of graphs there is a graph $I$ such that the edges $E(G)$ of a graph $G$ are bijective with the graph morphisms $I \to G$. If the category has a cartesian product and is also to be cartesian closed, this implies that the edges of the function graph $GRPH(H,G)$ are bijective with the morphisms $I \times H \to G$. Now you should be able to work out if the category defined in the question can be cartesian closed.

Comment: In http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/graphmorphisms-v15i1a1.pdf it's said "we need also a directed graph DGPH(B;C) with Dgph(B;C) as its set of vertices, and an exponential law". I need to know what DGPH(B;C) exactly is

Comment: @porton: the internal hom for reflexive digraphs is described in detail in Section 3. The edges of $DGPH(B,C)$ are the morphisms $I \times B \to C$.

Comment: Please describe explicitly the evaluation function for these exponential objects.

Comment: @RonnieBrown: I don't understand how morphisms $I \times B \to C$ are related with the definition 2.3 in the above mentioned article

Comment: It seems that an evaluation map is described by the formula $\operatorname{eval}((f;g);x) = (f(x);g(x))$. But I have not yet checked that it is really an evaluation map. Is my choice of proposed evaluation map right?