# Category theory - where is my error?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

In [Explicit formula for exponential objects in category of digraphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569458/explicit-formula-for-exponential-objects-in-category-of-digraphs/569824) and its answer

we have currying/uncurrying (which I will denote $\sim$ and $-$) as exponential transpose for the category $\mathbf{Dig}$ (as it is clear from the above referenced question).

Then accordingly Awodey's book evaluation $\epsilon=-\left(1_{\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)}\right)$ (for $\epsilon: \operatorname{MOR}(A;B)\times A\rightarrow B$).

Then substituting digraphs $p$ and $q$ we get: $\epsilon(p;q)=\left(-\left(1_{\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)}\right)\right)(p;q)=1_{\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)}(p)(q)=p(q)$, what is a nonsense because $p$ is a digraph not a function.

Where is my error?

---

With the help of the answers I realized my error (I have confused between the elements of digraph $\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)$ with the digraph itself) and am more near to perfect understanding of this issue. But one issue yet remains:

When $p$ is a vertex of $\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)$ (that is a function) it is clear. But $p$ may also be an edge and an edge is not a function. Thus $p(q)$ does not make sense. I don't understand this.

Comment: Your notation is not clear: what you mean by $\epsilon(p;q)$ the application of the digraphs $p$ and $q$ to $\epsilon$? in that case why you should be allowed to do the third passage, namely $1_{MOR(A;B)}(p)(q)$?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: $\epsilon(p;q)$ is $\epsilon$ function applied to the ordered pair $(p;q)$ of digraphs. $1_{MOR(A;B)}(p)(q)$ means the result of $1_{MOR(A;B)}(p)$ applied to the digraph $q$.

Comment: if $\epsilon$ is a morphism of digraphs $p$ and $q$ shouldn't be vertexes in the digraphs respectively  $MOR(A;B)$ and $A$?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: It isn't the category of graphs. It is the category of (discretely) continuous maps between digraphs. Objects are digraphs not vertexes and edges

Comment: objects are digraphs...so morphisms are morphisms of digraphs, and so functions between the vertex-sets of the digraphs preserving the relation of the digraphs. Am I wrong?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: I mostly understood it, but one issue remains. Please see the updated question

Comment: could you link any reference to a complete description of $MOR(A;B)$?

Comment: $\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)$ (often designated $B^A$) is the exponential object as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object or http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/exponential+object in our special case it is... (see the next comment)

Comment: For the category $\mathbf{Dig}$ exponential $\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)$ is the digraph whose vertexes are functions $\operatorname{Ob}A\rightarrow\operatorname{Ob}B$ and whose edges are such pairs $(f;g)$ of functions that $\forall (v;w) \in \operatorname{GR} A : ( f(v); g(w)) \in \operatorname{GR} B$ (where $\operatorname{Ob} X$ is the set of vertices of a digraph $X$ and $\operatorname{GR} X$ is the set of edges of a digraph $X$).

Comment: as I told you your equation is wrong also for other reason: is not true that $-(1_{MOR(A;B)})(p;q)=1_{MOR(A;B)}(p)(q)$

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: Isn't it true by definition of currying? Why do you mind it is wrong?

Comment: It works just for generalized elements, not for object in general.

Comment: More importantly why should you apply an edge to a graph morphisms?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: It seems it is my error what you have pointed "It works just for generalized elements, not for object in general". But I do not 100% understand what is it exactly. Could you be so grateful to completely explain my last error?

Comment: as you defined else where a digraph morphism is a function between the sets of vertex of graph. Since $\epsilon$ is morphism from the digraph $MOR(A;B) \times A$ to the digraph $B$ it cannot be applied to edges, so $p$ and $q$ must be both vertesx of the digraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's fix a little a notation. Suppose we are working in a category $\mathcal C$ cartesian closed, that means that $\mathcal C$ is closed for product and that the product have a right adjoint, the bifunctor $[-,-] \colon \mathcal C \times \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$.
Let's 
$$\varphi \colon \mathcal C(X \times Y,Z) \cong \mathcal C(X,[Y,Z])$$
be the adjunction.

In you notation $MOR(X;Y)=[X,Y]$ and for every $f \colon X \to  [Y,Z]$ we have $- f=\varphi^{-1}(f)$.

As you said $\epsilon = \varphi^{-1}(1_{[X,Y]})$ is the evaluation. 
Since you work with $\mathcal C = \mathbf{Digrph}$ the category of digraphs the morphisms becomes digraphs morphism the espression 
$\epsilon(p,q)$ have sense if and only if $p \in [X,Y]$ and $q \in X$, i.e. iff $p$ and $q$ are vertexes of the digraphs.

That said your third passage
$$\varphi^{-1}(1_{[X,Y]})(p,q) = 1_{[X,Y]}(p)(q)$$
or in your notation 
$$-(1_{MOR(X;Y)})(p;q)=1_{MOR(X;Y)}(p)(q)$$
is not legit.

What could be legit is a passage of the form
$$\varphi^{-1}(1_{[X,Y]})\circ p \times q = \varphi([q,Y] \circ 1_{[X,Y]}\circ p)$$
where $p \colon T \to [X,Y]$ and $q \colon U \to X$ morphisms of digraphs.

Comment: Yes, I confused the set $\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)$ itself with elements of this set. Thanks for explaining, I will upvote your answer

Comment: And I will nominate you for the Abel prize lol

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you wrote, $\epsilon:\text{MOR}(A;B)\times A\to B$, the first of the two arguments of $\epsilon$ should be a morphism, not a digraph.  So of course you get nonsense when you use a digraph $p$ as the first argument.

Comment: By $\operatorname{MOR}(A;B)$ I mean the __internal__ morphisms (=categorical exponentials) from $A$ to $B$. Internal morphisms are objects (digraphs in our case)

Comment: @porton So then your $p$ and $q$ should be elements f those digraphs, i.e., vertices or edges.  A vertex of the internal-Hom digraph amounts to a function, so again $p$ will be a function and no nonsense ensues.

Comment: Again no: objects of category $\mathbf{Dig}$ are digraphs. $p$ and $q$ are objects that is digraphs, not vertexes or edges.

Comment: @porton Why would $p$ and $q$ be objects of the category? Isn't $\epsilon$ supposed to be a morphism of the category?  More precisely, $\epsilon$ is a natural transformation, whose component at a pair of objects $A,B$ is a morphism from $\text{MOR}(A;B)\times A$ to $B$. That would be a homomorphism of digraphs, so it takes as arguments elements (vertices or edges) of the digraphs.

Comment: When $p$ is a vertex (that is a function) it is clear. But $p$ may also be an edge and an edge is not a function. I don't understand this

Comment: Edges of $[A,B]$ correspond to graph homomorphisms
$g: E\times A \to B$ where $E = (0\to 1)$. Source and target of such
a $g$ (with components $g_V$ and $g_E$) are $g_V(0,-): |A| \to B$
and $g_V(1,-): |A| \to B$ where $|A|$ is the underlying discrete graph of $A$.
Given an edge $(g,x:a\to a')$ in $[A,B]\times A$, consider the edge
$\bar{x}:(0,a)\to(1,a')$ in $E\times A$ induced by $x$ and 
set $ev_E(g,x) = g_E(\bar{x})$.
Because of $ev_V(g_V(0,-),a) = g_V(0,a) = source(g_E(\bar{x})$
and $ev_V(g_V(1,-),a') = g_V(1,a') = target(g_E(\bar{x})$
this gives a homomorphism $ev: [A,B]\times A \to B$.